# How do I add an image to an HTML input widget?

Tags: html, css, forms, html-input

For example if you go to

https://github.com/signup/free

And type 'john' into username, a small red exclamation mark appears on the right hand side.  Forgetting about the JavaScript which I know how to do, how can you get an image into the text input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can display the image the same way i.e. on the right and just fitting inside the box:

```
<style type="text/css">
.input_error_bg {
    background-image: url("myimage.png");
    background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -khtml-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-position: right 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.input_bg {
    background: none;
}
</style>

<form action="signup.php" method="POST">
<input class="input_error_bg" type="text" />
</form>
```

Use javascript to change the className as necessary.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a CSS [backgound-image](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-image).

Ex:

```
input {
    background-image: url("/images/modules/ajax/error.png");
}
```

You can also specify the image by using the CSS [background shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Shorthand_properties).

Answer (score 1):

You can make the image part of the background of the input element.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a background image (so you can use a sprite icon, like jQuery UI), you can use absolute positioning to overlay the icon.

Example (untested):

```
<div style='display: inline-block; position: relative;'>
    <input type=text />
    <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert ui-state-error' style='position: absolute; display: block; margin-top: -8px; top: 50%; right: 4px;' />
</div>
```